NullPointerException crash with no idea how to replicate
I've noticed a weird crashlog that keeps me awake at nights in google play console of my app.
The crashlog looks like this.
at com.[redacted].main.GameViewModel.nFragments (GameViewModel.java:223)
at com.[redacted].main.ui.GameGuestFragmentListenFragment.lambda$onViewCreated$0$com-[redacted]-main-ui-GameGuestFragmentListenFragment (GameGuestFragmentListenFragment.java:106)
at com.[redacted].main.ui.GameGuestFragmentListenFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.onChanged (D8$$SyntheticClass)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify (LiveData.java:133)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue (LiveData.java:146)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged (LiveData.java:468)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged (LiveData.java:425)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent (LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass (LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync (LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState (LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent (LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent (FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:62)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart (Fragment.java:3028)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start (FragmentStateManager.java:589)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:300)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStore.java:112)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1647)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:3126)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart (FragmentManager.java:3077)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart (FragmentController.java:262)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:510)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:178)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1455)
at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:8129)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:3708)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:222)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:202)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:174)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:98)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2252)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7941)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:553)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1003)

However, attempting to simulate the crash (e.g. throwing an exception on the same line)
the crashlog looks slightly different from what is displayed above:
at com.[redacted].main.GameViewModel.nFragments(GameViewModel.java:223)
at com.[redacted].main.ui.GameGuestFragmentListenFragment.lambda$onViewCreated$0$com-[redacted]-main-ui-GameGuestFragmentListenFragment(GameGuestFragmentListenFragment.java:106)
at com.[redacted].main.ui.GameGuestFragmentListenFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.onChanged(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:146)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:468)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:425)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:62)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3028)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:589)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1971)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:305)
at com.[redacted].GameActivity.onStateChanged(GameActivity.java:152)
at com.[redacted].GameActivity.$r8$lambda$jja-qOkaQBESGimLB8neKRHuMXU(Unknown Source:0)
at com.[redacted].GameActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onChanged(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:93)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

the curious part: in my attempt there a trace from my code on the lines 21-23, but the same trace from console does not show it.
at com.[redacted].GameActivity.onStateChanged(GameActivity.java:152)
at com.[redacted].GameActivity.$r8$lambda$jja-qOkaQBESGimLB8neKRHuMXU(Unknown Source:0)
at com.[redacted].GameActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onChanged(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)

A bit of relevant background of this app:
There's GameActivity that replaces Fragments depending on the state. Fragments are replaced via observation of LiveData changes on the Activity issued from GameViewModel. LiveData observer is bound to getViewLifecycleOwner() of fragments
What I have been able to rule out so far:

this is not caused by a race-condition, the accessed object is created way before
the object is not null, as it is accessed before

What could it be:

There is a way to reach this part of code bypassing previous checks - I have not found a way yet
Memory issue, the required object is being released (a tinfoil-hat theory), however I was not able to confirm it either due to the limited access to lower-end android devices

Questions:
What is the reason of "why GameActivity is not visible in the crashlog in google console" and could it be a clue to resolving this issue?
Thanks in advance
